# How to log static file request in JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

Is there a way to log the requests coming for static files (like index.html or js files) in JHipster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a filter:

```
public class RequestLoggingFilter implements Filter {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AuditFilter.class);

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    String requestUrl = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
    String requestMethod = httpRequest.getMethod();
    log.info("Received " + requestMethod + " request + " for " + requestUrl);


    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

}

Comment: Great, glad to hear it worked. Please accept the answer then.